# Linksys EA9500 v1.1 broadcasts 2.4 GHz band incorrectly ( 2.4 GHz broadcasted as 5.0 GHz band)

Tags: router, wireless-router

As in title, I'm searching for help in configuration for my Linksys router. It currently has very poor 2.4Ghz coverage and its signal drop ~ 50% at 70in far and lost after a wall. After investigation, I figure out the 2.4GHz band broadcasts at 5GHz ac mode (channel 36).

Other configuration works fine, such as: change SSID name, enable, disable, change password. However, everything is visible at 5GHz band; includes guest 2.4 ssid

I'm digging every where but it seems a myth to me. Hoping to have your advices for my case to set 2.4 band broadcast 2.4 GHz instead broadcasting 5GHz like now

Current:

```
2.4 GHz band broadcast on channel 36; 5GHz
5.0 GHz band broadcast on channel 36; 5GHz
```

Expected:

```
2.4 GHz band broadcast on channel 1-11; 2.4 GHz
5.0 GHz band broadcast on channel 36; 5 GHz
```

Much appreciated.

Configured
[image: Configured]

Actual broadcast
[image: Actual broadcast]

Answer (score -1):

You should have read the documentation on your device and Disable Band Steering
https://www.linksys.com/support-article?articleNum=274488

Comment: Before downvote check what asker asks at first place when this answer was posted https://superuser.com/revisions/1740365/1

Comment: Before complaining about downvotes, you should read our guidelines on answers; answers should avoid just pointing to documentation, you should quote and cite the relevant information.  If a question is incomplete or confusing, you should ask for clarification before you submit an answer.

Comment: In this case, my downvote is because it's a link-only answer. You have failed to explain within your answer in your own words the reason Linksys03608_5GHz isn't being listed.  While the reason is due to band steering, and the article you provided explains that reason, without the article itself, your answer wouldn't be helpful when Linksys decides to delete the article in 5 years  You could easily solve the problem with your answer, and an upvote would certainly follow, provided the correct article for the correct hardware is used as a reference.

Comment: This dude shouldnt complain it is a myth without reading documentation beforehand. I just tell him what his myth is

Comment: Thanks for answering, however the point here Linksys03608 is broadcasting as 5GHz instead of 2.4GHz. Disable band steering come with the same result since it's a tri band (meant 2.4+5+5 bands). Tried to disable steering before posting question but no help. Only 1 reason it comes like this is hardware issue which I hoped it's not. I want to know is there any wrong configuration or twists I need to make or not

Comment: You have 5+5 switch ON in right low corner. Did you try OFF it and disable  steering

Comment: turning of 5+5 in right down corner will turn off both 5GHz broadcasting. Aka, only Linksys03608 shows in the list, and of course it broadcasts as 5Ghz band

Comment: There is wifi mode mixed and channel auto under 2.4. Try to change both Is it old what firmware it has?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Already set it to g mode and channel 1/6/9/11 but no luck :(; it keeps broadcasting as ac mode channel 36. It currently is with 1.1.8.204089 (latest firmware); reset default configuration but nothing works.

Comment: Do you have some another device with 2.4ghz support to check it with your router?

Comment: I have 2 other 2.4 usb adapters and they  cannot see any broadcasted network. Guessing, returning it might be a good choice.

Comment: Try disable 5, reboot, enable 5, reboot, maybe reset to factory defaults like here https://internet-access-guide.com/2-4ghz-not-working-5ghz-working-linksys/